# Swift 2.0 protocol extensions - typealias

Tags: swift, generics, protocols

I am trying to have a extend a protocol in the following way but I am getting the error: Cannot convert return expression of type typable to typable.

I thought by saying `typalias MyType : inside` MyType will have to be an entity that conforms to `inside`

```
struct typeable<T> {
    let value : String = "hello world"
}

protocol inside {
        func __myFunction() -> typeable<inside>
}  

protocol outside : inside {
    typealias MyType : inside

    func myFunction() -> typeable<MyType>
}

extension outside {
    final func __myFunction() -> typeable<inside> {
        return self.myFunction()
    }
}

struct thing : outside {
    typealias MyType = thing

    func myFunction() -> typeable<thing> {
        return typeable<thing>()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `inside` protocol:

```
protocol inside {
    func __myFunction() -> typeable<inside>
}
```

... requires a function with a return type `typeable<inside>`, which is not the same as `typeable<T>` where `T: inside`. On the other hand, the default implementation of the conforming candidate function in the extension of `outside` returns a `typeable<MyType>` where `MyType` has not been up-casted to `inside`...

The following code, however, or some variant thereof, may express your intent (as far as I understand it) without tripping up the compiler:

```
struct Typeable<T> {
    init(_: T) {}
}

extension Typeable : CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String { return "I'm a \(self.dynamicType)" }
}

protocol InsideType {
    func asTypeableInside() -> Typeable<Self>
}

protocol OutsideType : InsideType {
    func asTypeableOutside() -> Typeable<Self>
}

extension OutsideType {
    func asTypeableInside() -> Typeable<Self> {
        return asTypeableOutside()
    }
}

struct Outside {}

extension Outside : OutsideType {
    func asTypeableOutside() -> Typeable<Outside> {
        return Typeable(self)
    }
}
```

... with following properties:

```
let o = Outside()
let x = o.asTypeableOutside()
print( o )                                       // prints: Outside()
print( x )                                       // prints: I'm a Typeable<Outside>
o is InsideType                                  // always true
x is Typeable<InsideType>                        // always false

Typeable(o) is Typeable<Outside>                 // always true
Typeable(o) is Typeable<OutsideType>             // always false
Typeable(o) is Typeable<InsideType>              // always false
```

... bearing in mind that:

```
5 is CustomStringConvertible                     // always true
Typeable(5) is Typeable<CustomStringConvertible> // always false
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't appear that the `typealias MyType : inside` within the `outside` protocol is visible in the `outside` extension. I was able to get the extension to compile by putting the `typealias MyType = inside` (note the `=` rather than `:`), but that made the `thing` struct error on compilation.

It's difficult to figure out what you're actually trying to do, more context would be helpful to fully grasp the problem at hand.

Answer (score 0):

In the definition `__myFunction` in the extension to `outside`, the uninstantiated type `MyType` can be of any type which inherits `inside`, which may be instantiated anywhere `outside` is implemented. So returning a `typeable<inside>` as being of `typeable<MyType>` simply proved to be type mismatch.

You, however, can avoid the error changing the definition a little bit.

```
struct typeable<T> {
    let value : String = "hello world"
}

protocol inside {
    typealias MyType
    func __myFunction() -> typeable<MyType>
}

protocol outside : inside {
    typealias MyType : inside
    func myFunction() -> typeable<MyType>
}

extension outside {
    final func __myFunction() -> typeable<MyType> {
        return self.myFunction()
    }
}

struct thing : outside {
    typealias MyType = thing
    func myFunction() -> typeable<thing> {
        return typeable<thing>()
    }
}
```